# Passing self arguments to callback function in separate method

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to refactor my code and break things to learn and I broke something, hope you can help me learn.

I got a working scraper that runs over multiple pages as follows:

```
class someSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider_name'
    allowed_domains = ['www.example.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com&page=1']


    def parse(self, response): 
        result_parsed = json.loads(result)
        results = result_parsed.get('results') #yield actual results
        current_page_number = result_parsed.get('currentPage') #gets the page from the link as part of the API response
        
        for result in results:
            count += 1
            
           yield{ 

            ... #gives me the results as desired
     
            }

        go_to_nextpage(self, current_page_number) #### THIS DOES NOT WORK, not error, just stops at one page ####

        #### THIS WORKS ####
        # next_page_number = result_parsed.get('currentPage') +1
        # yield scrapy.Request(
        #     url=f'https://www.immoweb.be/en/search-results/house-and-apartment/for-sale/brussels/district?countries=BE&hasRecommendationActivated=true&page={next_page_number}&orderBy=relevance&searchType=similar',
        #     callback=self.parse
        # )
```

With next_page_number() defined as:

```
def go_to_nextpage(self, current_page_number):
    next_page_number = current_page_number +1
    yield scrapy.Request(
        url=f'https://www.example.com&page={next_page_number}',
        callback=self.parse
    )
```

I'm guessing I don't properly understand 2 things:

- the working of the self keyword
- the way the callback method and the parse method work / interact

any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you please specify what exactly do you not understand?

Comment: `self` is not a keyword.  It's just an argument name.  When you do `object.function()` to call an object method, Python automatically passes the object as the first parameter.  By long-standing convention, we call that argument `self` so we can access the object's members and functions.  When you say `self.parse` without calling it, that creates a "pre-bound" function that knows it has to pass `self` as the first parameter when it eventually gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues that I can hopefully help clarify.

1. You are not using the `self` parameter correctly.

   - In python, when you call a class method like this: `myclass.method()`; `myclass` is the variable for the an instance of the class.
   - When the same method is called from inside another instance method the `self` variable, which is automatically injected as the first parameter, is used instead: `self.method()`.
   - In the context of your code it should look like this `self.go_to_nextpage(current_page_number)`

---

2. Scrapy can only process requests that are returned/yielded from the it's parser callback.

   - You correctly yield the first items as you indicated, but request that is yielded by the `go_to_nextpage` method because your current code doesn't do anything with the return value.
   - Another issue is that you are yielding a single result in `go_to_nextpage` which automatically turns that method into a generator
   - The easiest solution to this is to simply return the request instead of yielding it.

Here is an example of what it should look like:

```
class someSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider_name'
    allowed_domains = ['www.example.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com&page=1']

    def parse(self, response): 
        result_parsed = json.loads(result)
        results = result_parsed.get('results')
        current_page_number = result_parsed.get('currentPage') 
        for result in results:
            count += 1
            yield{ something } 
        # go_to_nextpage(self, current_page_number) <- this line is the issue
        # because you don't handle the return value.
        yield self.go_to_nextpage(current_page_number)



    def go_to_nextpage(self, current_page_number):
        next_page_number = current_page_number +1
        return scrapy.Request(url=(f'https://www.immoweb.be/en/search-results/house-and-apartment/for-sale/brussels/district?countries=                 BE&hasRecommendationActivated=true&page={next_page_number}&orderBy=relevance&searchType=similar',
                              callback=self.parse)
```

If you wanted to use yield in your `go_to_nextpage` method you could write it like this.

```
class someSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def parse(self, request):
        ...
        # because you don't handle the return value.
        for i in self.go_to_nextpage(current_page_number):
            yield

    def go_to_nextpage(self, current_page_number):
        next_page_number = current_page_number +1
        yield scrapy.Request(url=(f'https://www.immoweb.be/en/search-results/house-and-apartment/for-sale/brussels/district?countries=                 BE&hasRecommendationActivated=true&page={next_page_number}&orderBy=relevance&searchType=similar',
                              callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was hoping for. Still a little fuzzy, hopefully it comes with practice.
I understand the self.method() part now, and the part where I should yield the go_to_nextpage() method. 
I don’t understand why it works with return and not yield. I understood that Yield is like return but that you can have more than one in a method + stores local variables

Comment: @Kellerness  see the additional I made to my answer.  You certainly could use yield it, however sincy using yield turns the function into a generator it would just need to be written differently